# Why putting queue can solve data inconsistency?

Tags: message-queue, distributed-system, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

I am looking into a tool called Cadence, which can be used to lower the complexity of developing distributed systems.

I came across this video, https://youtu.be/llmsBGKOuWI?t=108.

Starting from 1:40, he mentioned that when sending a transaction, which include debit and credit, if either one of the operation failed, consistency issue will occur, and we can solve it by putting a queue.

The speaker did not mentioned the reason of it, and I'm thinking that is it because queue can enable replay message? Or there is some other reasons that I missed?

Any answers or opinions are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queues have the ability to persist the messages for a short amount of time, so if any of your server fails, you can still get the message from queue and retry, I guess this is what he means.